# Asking What's the logic?

Tags: translation, word-choice

If i want to ask what is the logic behind something does :その中の論理は何ですか
Work?

Comment: そのすじみちは何ですか should work for you

Comment: Do you mean the logic of a machine/system, or the logic of someone's opinion?

Comment: Opinion i guess. More specifically, what's the logic /sense behind a decision someone made

Answer (score 2):

It depends on context.
・どういう理由ですか？
・どういう理屈ですか？

More polite way
「そのご意見の理由をお伺いできますか？」

Answer (score 0):

If you and the other person are talking about the decision, you can just ask "どうしてそう決まったんですか？" or "どうしてそうなったんですか？"

To be more polite, you can also ask "どうしてその決定になったのか、教えていただけますか？"